# Validation rule is still firing even when requirements are met

Tags: validation-rule, opportunity

Hello Salesforce Experts,
I am hitting a wall on this validation rule I'm working on and hoping to get some help. My scenario is the validation rule should be checking for 3 criteria:

1. Stage is being changed to 'Close Pending';
2. The Record Type is Renewal;
3. The difference between the True Renewal and Expected Renewal amounts is less than 0.

If all these are true then we want the users to populate the custom fields "Downsell Reasons"and "Downsell Details". The validation works just fine, it fires when these 3 are true. Where I'm having trouble is that it won't go away even after I fill in the Downsell Reasons and Downsell Details. Here is my current formula:

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(StageName,"Close Pending"),
    RecordType.Name = "Renewal",
    True_Renewal__c-Expected_Renewal_Amount__c < 0,
    OR(
        ISBLANK(TEXT(Downsell_Reason__c)),
        ISBLANK(Downsell_Details__c)
    )
)
```

After the rule fires, I populated both fields but it does not seem to satisfy my validation rule and won't let me save the record. Can anybody help pls? [image]

Comment: try this AND(
    ISCHANGED(StageName),
    ISPICKVAL(StageName,"Close Pending"),
    RecordType.Name = "Renewal",
    (True_Renewal__c - Expected_Renewal_Amount__c) < 0,
    OR(
        ISBLANK(TEXT(Downsell_Reason__c)),
        ISBLANK(Downsell_Details__c)
    )
)

Comment: are there any before save flows or triggers that adjust True_Renewal__c or Expected_Renewal_Amount__c if the two Downsell_Reason_xxx fields are nonNull?